# Matplotlib: Mix integer and float ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, integer, axes

For my pyplot axes, I want to use the following ticks:

```
ticks = [-5.0, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0.128]
```

(These strange values are calculated and will change dynamically.)

But there are 2 important details I want to realise: The first and the last value should be a float number to see the exact values at the beginning and the end. The values between shall only be integers to keep it readable.

To set the ticks, I did

```
axes = plt.subplot()
axes.set_xticks(ticks)
```

And I get what I want, but it looks bad because my integer values are still printed as float values with 3 decimals.

[image: Ticks]

I want to get ticks `-5.000, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0.128` and not `-5.000, -4.000, ...`.

Any idea what I can do to solve this? Thank you! :)

Comment: I think it helps to understand that the *ticks* are *always* floating point numbers. You can't even change that. But the tick*labels* are always strings; so they can be anything you like (`"0", "quarter", "yesterday", "500.001", "ülügüü"`). You can set the ticks via `set_xticks`, you can set the labels via `set_xticklabels`. (Just make sure to *always* set the ticks in case you set the labels - the inverse would not be critical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817967/matplotlib-mix-integer-and-float-ticks#comment96412051_54817967), I was able to solve it quickly. Thank you very much!

For other people with the same problem:

```
ticks = [-5.0, -4, -3, -2, -1, -0.128]
tickLabels = map(str, ticks)

axes = plt.subplot()
axes.set_xticks(ticks)
axes.set_xticklabels(tickLabels)
```